# DurandalJS: Keeping data across a session

Tags: javascript, durandal, durandal-2.0

I have decided to create a separate folder called "controllers" for my AJAX requests, models and data arrays, so in case I will need the same requests on multiple pages, I wouldn't have to repeat my code.

So for example on 'app/page1/index.html' I have a list of all the users:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: usersArr }">
  <li data-bind="text: full_name"></li>
</ul>
```

I would require the user controller in page1's viewmodel and then load the data through it:

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout', 'controllers/user/index'], function ($, ko, User) {
  var Page1 = function() {
    this.usersArr = User.usersArr;
  };

  Page1.prototype.activate = function() {
    User.getUsers();
  };

  return Page1;
});
```

And this is the User controller:

```
define(['knockout', './models',], function (ko, Model) {
  var UserController = function() {
    this.usersArr = ko.observableArray();
  };

  // inherit
  UserController.prototype.Model = new Model();

  UserController.prototype.getUsers = function () {
    // ajax goes here, data comes back,
    // put it through the Model and then save it to usersArr();
  };

  UserController.prototype.addUser = function () { ... };
  UserController.prototype.removeUser = function () { ... };

  return new UserController();
});
```

Notice that I return the controller as an object. I did this so that it stays in memory and I could reuse the code on other pages (especially the observable array with the stored data). Now if I create a 'page2' for example and require the same list, the users would be already loaded in the `usersArr` observable array.

I have multiple controllers like this one that the app will use throughout a session. I just wanted to know if there were any downsides to this method, like app slow-downs or any other problems I may encounter. I'd also love to know if you guys have a different approach to keeping your data across a session.

Thanks!

Comment: Are these separate pages, as in separate HTML pages that all hit the server? Or are these separate views on the same page?

Comment: This questions seems like it would be more appropriate on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: 'Page1', 'Page2', etc are all separate views, each with their own viewmodel inside a SPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way that I've found to keep information around in a SPA is to create a singleton and reference that singleton in all views.

For instance, this is a modified version of one of mine:

```
define([], function() {
    "use strict";
    var countryList: []    


    return {
      countryList: countryList,

    };
});
```

And then I simply require that on all of my SPAs.  CountryList is filled in by the first view[1] and the data is available to all the others.

[1] in this context we are making a wizard, so they *must* go through views in order.

Answer (score 0):

I use the browser built in local storage / session storage to store session parameters. ie in js:

```
// set data    
sessionStorage["key"] = someJsVar;
// get data
var myJsVar = sessionStorage["key"];
```